# Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown in Nuxt 2 APP with Eslint

Tags: nuxt.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a nuxt 2 application with nuxt 2 composition api. My node version is 14.20.0.

I'm trying to run:

```
npx eslint --fix .
```

And I'm getting this ERROR message:

```
.eslintrc.js » @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript » @nuxtjs/eslint-config:
        Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
```

A couple of premises, unfortunately I can't update the node version due to compatibility issues (this is an APP that' still using a Nuxt 2 configuration), I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065765/eslint-jest-globals-environment-key-unknown) and here and they are not working for me. I'm not using jest at all but apparently @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript force you to do some sort of jest configuration on the .eslintrc.js file.

If I remove @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript the command works. Downgrading Typescript is also not an option in my case.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "modelmanagement",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "nuxt:dev": "nuxt",
        "nuxt:build": "nuxt build --modern",
        "nuxt:build-analyze": "nuxt build --modern --analyze",
        "nuxt:start": "nuxt start --modern --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 80",
        "nuxt:export": "nuxt export",
        "nuxt:serve": "nuxt serve",
        "nuxt:docker": "nuxt --modern --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 80",
        "nuxt:generate": "nuxt generate --fail-on-error",
        "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint": "npm run lint:js",
        "lint:all": "eslint --ext .ts,.js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "lint:fix-all": "cross-env npm run lint:all -- --fix",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input": "^1.0.8",
        "@mdi/js": "^5.8.55",
        "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
        "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.29.2",
        "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
        "@vueuse/core": "^4.11.2",
        "awe-dnd": "0.3.4",
        "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.2.2",
        "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
        "jszip": "^3.1.3",
        "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
        "lazysizes": "^5.2.2",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.21",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
        "nanoid": "^2.1.11",
        "node-cache": "^4.2.1",
        "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
        "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.10",
        "nuxt-health": "0.0.1",
        "nuxt-i18n": "^6.27.0",
        "nuxt-responsive-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "party-js": "^2.0.1",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "sharp": "^0.30.7",
        "swiper": "^5.4.5",
        "ts-md5": "^1.2.9",
        "v-body-scroll-lock": "^1.1.3",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.0",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
        "vue-demi": "0.11.4",
        "vue-lazy-hydration": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
        "vue-masonry-wall": "^0.3.1",
        "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.7",
        "vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.10",
        "vue-virtual-scroll-list": "^2.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
        "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^6.0.1",
        "@nuxtjs/router-extras": "^1.1.0",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
        "@types/recurly__recurly-js": "^4.16.1",
        "@types/swiper": "^5.4.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.5",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.3.0",
        "sass": "^1.69.3",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "typescript": "^4.3.2"
    }
}
```

This is my eslint configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', 'plugin:nuxt/recommended'],
    plugins: ['prettier'],
    rules: {
        quotes: ['error', 'single'],
        semi: ['error', 'always'],
        'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
        'vue/no-v-html': 'off',
        'padding-line-between-statements': [
            'error',
            { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'export' },
            { blankLine: 'never', prev: 'export', next: 'export' },
        ],
    },
};
```